# Minecraft wont run

Tags: minecraft

Hi this is the error message

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oh - I know what I did wrong!

Time: 3/27/13 10:53 AM
Description: Failed to start game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f87780096b0 serial: 145 error: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) request_code: 154 minor_code: 24
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:268)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Context.java:120)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:858)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:235)
    at avv.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.1
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.5.0-17-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_15, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 405695400 bytes (386 MB) / 514523136 bytes (490 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xmx1024M -Xms512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 4):

The core error here is an X error: `BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)`. You'll see this if you don't have enough video memory available for something.

Recommendations:

- Get a better graphics card with a decent amount of video memory
- If you're on a laptop where the video card shares system RAM, go into the BIOS at boot and allocate more memory to your graphics card.

Otherwise, please edit the question to include more information about your computer hardware.